# US citizen exited Spain on a yacht

Tags: schengen, paperwork

I am a US citizen. I exited Spain on a yacht and sailed to the US. We had a crazy departure and I didn't get the Schengen exit stamp. What would happen when I return to Schengen?

Comment: Did you get an US entry stamp, showing when you entered the US, by any chance?

Comment: No the US does not stamp the US passports on entry even in the airports. But in the marina we just got out of the boat and went home, with no passport control

Comment: @Costable You should have undergone passport control, or at least report your arrival to CBP, depending on your situation ([link](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/pleasure-boats), if you haven't done that, you might encounter some issues on next arrival/departures (very unlikely but still possible) as it is illegal not to be vetted by CBP if you are entering by boat

Answer (score 5):

> What would happen when I return to Schengen?

Probably nothing.  If, however, the passport inspector notices that there is an entry stamp that lacks a corresponding exit stamp, Article 12 of the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02016R0399-20190611) will come into play.  Here it is in full:

> ## Article 12
>
> Presumption as regards fulfilment of conditions of duration of stay
>
> 1. If the travel document of a third-country national does not bear an entry stamp, the competent national authorities may presume that the holder does not fulfil, or no longer fulfils, the conditions of duration of stay applicable within the Member State concerned.
> 2. The presumption referred to in paragraph 1 may be rebutted where the third-country national provides, by any means, credible evidence, such as transport tickets or proof of his or her presence outside the territory of the Member States, that he or she has respected the conditions relating to the duration of a short stay.
>    In such a case:
>    (a) where the third-country national is found on the territory of a Member State applying the Schengen acquis in full, the competent authorities shall indicate, in accordance with national law and practice, in his or her travel document the date on which, and the place where, he or she crossed the external border of one of the Member States applying the Schengen acquis in full;
>    (b) where the third-country national is found on the territory of a Member State in respect of which the decision contemplated in Article 3(2) of the 2003 Act of Accession, in Article 4(2) of the 2005 Act of Accession and in Article 4(2) of the 2011 Act of Accession has not been taken, the competent authorities shall indicate, in accordance with national law and practice, in his or her travel document the date on which, and the place where, he or she crossed the external border of such a Member State.
>    In addition to the indications referred to in points (a) and (b), a form as shown in Annex VIII may be given to the third-country national.
>    Member States shall inform each other and the Commission and the Council General Secretariat of their national practices with regard to the indications referred to in this Article.
> 3. Should the presumption referred to in paragraph 1 not be rebutted, the third-country national may be returned in accordance with Directive 2008/115/EC of the European Parliament and of the Council ( 12 ) and with national law respecting that Directive.
> 4. The relevant provisions of paragraphs 1 and 2 shall apply mutatis mutandis in the absence of an exit stamp.

Basically, if they call you out on the lack of a stamp, you can show whatever evidence you can to show that you've been outside the Schengen area.

Comment: Do they manually go by the passport stamps when I re-enter Schengen or I will be automatically flagged in some database as two entries with no exit in between?

Comment: @Costable yes, they check manually (see article 8(3)(a)(iii) in addition to article 12).  They're implementing an entry-exit database but it is not yet in use.  They will revise the code when it goes online.

Comment: In other words OP can just replace their US passport if they’re particularly worried about future problems at the border.